# Pygame and Java JDK 13 installation troubles

Tags: java, python, pygame

Good morning guys,

trying to install the Pygame library on my MacBook Pro...
I encountered some issues that I'm sure you're able to help me with!

- First of all I installed the last Python version (3.7.4)
- Than I tried to install via pip the Pygame library, but the process
  was unsuccessful due to the lack of a Java JKD 13.
- I downloaded and installed the last JDK 13 version (Jdk-13_osx-x64)
  and this process appeared to be successful.

Trying again to finally install the Pygame library an error occurred:

> Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt

Can anyone of you guys help me???

Thanks prior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python and Java developers using macOS, I personally recommend installing `Python` and `Java` through `HomeBrew`.

> Before you can start your journey as a software developer, you should install `Xcode` and `xcode-select` first which is mandatory.
>   You can install `Xcode` from Mac `AppStore` and `xcode-select` through the following command:
>
> ```
> xcode-select --install
> ```

After installing the prerequisites, you can install `HomeBrew` via:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Which is referenced from [here](https://brew.sh)

After you've installed `HomeBrew` you can install `Python3` and `AdoptopenJDK` via the following command:

```
brew install python3
brew cask install adoptopenjdk
```

> `AdoptopenJDK` is an open source JDK recommended by myself other than Oracle JDK.

Comment: Good, I followed you indications in a precise way. That's good till the Jdk installation. After that, trying to install the pygame library, bash gave me an error: my pip version is out to date, but using the pip install update procedure I wasn't able to reach the goal.

Comment: perhaps you've missed up the `warning` with `error`, and if you would like to update pip, use `pip3 install -U pip`

Comment: Perfect! Your suggestion was great to solve the pip update problem. I encountered another problem, the last step of my developer path is to install the Pygame library as sad up.... if I try to do it I reach this error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement --user (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for --user

Comment: @168grani I Strongly suggest that you should install the `pygame` library through pip, here the command that works for me: `pip3 install pygame`

Answer (score 1):

Apt used to be a command coming with the Java Development Kit around Java 6.

Java 6 is also the latest 32-bit version provided by Apple but that doesn’t run on the newest version of Mac OS.

I think you should look for a newer version of pygame compatible with your system.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll try to find a new version of the library mentioned...